# Xpath expression creating a TOC (html) from a xml source

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

For learning purposes I am working on a lightweight XSLT for a docbook document. My problem is generating the TOC
I guess my XPath expression is wrong but I can't figure out the right expression. Please find below snippets of my files. I use Saxon9.5 to translate from XML to HTML.

The Stylesheet

```
<!-- Stylesheet -->
<xsl:template match='db:toc'>
    <div id='toc'>
        <h1>Table of contents</h1>
        <ol>
            <!-- This line is not working. -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select='db:chapter' mode='toc'/>
        </ol>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match='db:chapter' mode='toc'>
    <li>
        <a href='{generate-id()}'>
            <xsl:value-of select='title'/>
        </a>
    </li>
</xsl:template>
```

The Docbook source

```
<!-- XML source -->
<book xmlns='http://docbook.org/ns/docbook' xml:lang="en">
    <toc/>
    <chapter>
        <title>Chapter 01</title>
        <para>
            Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet candy. Muffin lemon drops soufflé croissant pastry jelly beans candy sweet 
            roll. 
        </para>
```

My HTML output

```
<!-- The HTML output -->
<div id="toc">
    <h1>Table of contents</h1>
    <ol></ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correctly it is this line not working...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select='db:chapter' mode='toc'/>
```

The reason being is that you are currently in a template that matches **toc**. However **chapter** is not a child element of **toc**, which is what the apply-templates is trying to select. It is actually a sibling. Try this instead

```
<xsl:apply-templates select='following-sibling::db:chapter' mode='toc'/>
```

Or maybe this (to get the **chapter** element that is a child of the parent of **toc**)

```
<xsl:apply-templates select='../db:chapter' mode='toc'/>
```